# Blob storage, c# private container with some files public

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

How is possible with Azure Blob Storage to upload a file into a private container, but make the file URL public accessible? (I.E view the file if using the URL in the browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for specific blobs in Azure storage in a private container. Creating a SAS will generate a unique URL to the file. You make the url valid for a certain time period and you can allow multiple operations (READ, CREATE, WRITE, DELETE), and optionally white list IP addresses that can access the url.